# Trying to make a "Hello World" AWS API Gateway GET API call from Android using Generated SDK

Tags: android, api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to get the AWS API gateway generated SDK to work, I've created an API gateway GET API which works fine when I hit the url from a browser/httpclient, but not with Android.

With Android, I'm trying to use the Android SDK that is generated by AWS API Gateway. The documented example I found is very unclear to me, it uses types and methods which do not exist in the AWS SDK:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-android.html

For example:

```
//     If the API exposes a 'GET /{a}/{b}/{op}'  method, you can call the following SDK method to invoke the request,

Result.output = client.aBOpGet(a, b, c)
```

I do not know what aBOpGET is suppose to be, nor do I know what Result is.

while I was able to follow along to build/import the jars, I couldn't follow their code example. So, I came up with this based on browsing the SDK code:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientFactory;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiRequest;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiResponse;

import Client.LambdaMicroserviceClient;


public class APIGatewayHandler extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //gateway
        ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory();
        final LambdaMicroserviceClient client = factory.build(LambdaMicroserviceClient.class);

        ApiRequest request = new ApiRequest("/QueryNetSumMinute");


        ApiResponse apiResponse = client.execute(request);
        int responseCode = apiResponse.getStatusCode();

        android.util.Log.v("Request: ", request.toString());
        android.util.Log.v("response Code: ", String.valueOf(responseCode));
        android.util.Log.v("response Status Text: ",    apiResponse.getStatusText());
        //android.util.Log.v("responseCode: ", String.valueOf(responseCode));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void var) {
        Log.d("onPostExecute", "complete");
    }
}
```

That runs fine, but on the client response I get a 403 Forbidden error when invoked.

I have info logging enabled on API gateway and I can see detailed information from an http request sent by a browser, but I see nothing from this Android code.

**What I suspect is happening, is that the client is hitting the BASE URL of the API without specifying the method "/QueryNetSumMinute" which from testing from a browser does indeed return 403**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it working, incase this helps anyone see below. I had to add request.getPath("/MyAPIName"), and some debugging code:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientFactory;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiRequest;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiResponse;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import Client.LambdaMicroserviceClient;


public class APIGatewayHandler extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //gateway
        ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory();
        final LambdaMicroserviceClient client = factory.build(LambdaMicroserviceClient.class);

        ApiRequest request = new ApiRequest();
request.withPath("/QueryNetSumMinute");

        ApiResponse apiResponse = client.execute(request);
        int responseCode = apiResponse.getStatusCode();

            String responseBody = "empty";
        try {
            responseBody   = convertStreamToString(apiResponse.getRawContent());
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("ERROR ", " failed reading response ");
        }

        android.util.Log.v("Request: ", request.toString());
        android.util.Log.v("response Code: ", String.valueOf(responseCode));
        android.util.Log.v("response Status Text: ",    apiResponse.getStatusText());
        android.util.Log.v("responseBody: ", responseBody);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void var) {
        Log.d("onPostExecute", "complete");
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```